# How do I set html table caption from code behind? ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have a table in my aspx page:

```
<table id="tbl" runat="server">
</table>
```

I need to set to set the table caption in the code behind, so that it renders as follows:

```
<table id="tbl" runat="server">
   <caption>Monthly savings</caption>
</table>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous response from Brad M is almost correct, you must add a runat="server" attribute, an ID attribute and set it to some value you see fit, and then on the server side code:

One big caveat thought, you need to place the caption before the table element, inside is not possible

```
idYouGave.InnerText = "Monthly savings";
```

Since you can't use the  directly inside the , do something like this to achieve what you want:

```
<tr>
  <th colspan="numOfCols"><caption>...</caption></th>
</tr>
```

Comment: Same comment to other post... this solution did not work.  Code does not compile.

Comment: you must use the id you have set on the caption: <caption id="idYouGave" runat="server">.... only after setting this, you can use that id in the code behind. Sometimes the designer.cs file doesn't update, try changing from markup to design view, and switch back.

Comment: I did use the id, but it does not compile when I add the line code (with the correct id).

Comment: just changed my answer, you have to use the caption outside the table, inside is not possible

Comment: that does make it compile, but it kind of defeats the purpose of the table caption.  Thank you though...

Comment: Table doesn't have caption.. best you can do is use a tr with th inside that spans across all columns: <tr><th colspan="numOfCols"><caption>...</caption></th></tr>

Answer (score 1):

Just add the runat="server" attribute to your caption element, as well as give it an ID. Then just refer to it in code behind as caption.InnerText = "Monthly savings";

Comment: just tried that and that did not work.  I get a compilation error saying that 'caption' does not exist in the current context.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. Control `HtmlTable` can contain `<tr>` and only them, everything else will be removed. Here is the full note [from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltable.aspx):

> A complex table model is not supported. You cannot have an HtmlTable
>   control with nested `<caption>, <col>, <colgroup>, <tbody>, <thead>, or
>   <tfoot>` elements. These elements are removed without warning and do
>   not appear in the output HTML. An exception will be thrown if you
>   attempt to programmatically add these table model elements to the
>   Control.Controls collection of the HtmlTable control.

Your options are either to switch to `asp:Table` control, or switch back to plain markup.

Comment: At least without considering ASP.NET is removing the element, from a render point of view, it's there: http://jsfiddle.net/tnBdr/

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by "switch back to plain markup"?

Comment: @RicardoRodrigues, of course it is possible in plain HTML. Unfortunately we have to consider ASP.NET rendering here, since this is where all the tags and controls, except for `<tr>`, are removed from `HtmlTable`.

Comment: @malkassem, remove `runat="server"` from table tag. It might cause other complications though, everything depends on your other needs. But at least it will give you a possibility to set the caption.